# Running docker via Docker Toolbox + kitematic in Windows 7 behind corporate Proxy and private repo

Tags: docker, windows-7, docker-toolbox

I am trying to run docker from private hub via Docker Toolbox for Windows + kitematic in Windows 7.

I run kinematic and from there Docker Cli.

My PC is behind corporate Proxy.

Before starting kitematic I do:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://MYPROXY:8080
SET HTTPS_PROXY=https://MYPROXY:8080
SET NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.99.100
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
```

When I do

```
docker run hello-world
```

it works.

When I try to run docker on image located in private repo

```
docker run -d --name blabla -e server_port=8088 -p 8088:8088 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:5000/rr2/rep:1.0.0
```

Get an error:

```
Unable to find image 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:5000/rr2/rep:1.0.0' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:5000/v2/: Tunnel or SSL Forbidden.
```

Update:
For People with windows 10 and regular docker - it works they also check check box:

> 'expose daemon tcp localhost 2375 without tls'

not sure if and how it's related.

Comment: The first thing, at least when it comes to networking, is: is the machine accepting requests on the specified port? So, what is the response of `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 5000` ? THEN we layer on SSL/TLS and work our way up the OSI stack.

Comment: telent returns: 400 Bad Request, http response with bad request, 
so it looks it does connect...

Comment: That gives us a direction! :) Before we can build the image you will need to figure out why your local image repo. is non-responsive.

Comment: but it returns http response so it's responsive... no? I mean if I try to telnet not existing address to response is different

Comment: My mistake. You are correct, a 400 is a HTTP response. Given that, can we use cURL or wget with a properly formatted request that the remote server accepts? Try to get a HTTP 2xx or 3xx response code.